# schemaSpy for php classes

Tags: php, reverse-engineering, class-diagram, schemaspy

Is there a schemaSpy+graphviz equivalent for creating class diagrams from existing PHP source code?

In schemaSpy+graphviz, you can create an ER diagram using an existing database. The output are html files that when a text in the diagram is clicked, a new page will be loaded containing the information about the clicked text, like what is seen in http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/sample/relationships.html. I would like to find a tool with the same output functionality. Is there an equivalent tool for this in reverse engineering PHP classes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could give UML Lab (http://uml-lab.com) a try (Note: I'm biased as I'm working for Yatta Solutions ;) ). There is a tutorial explaining how to reverse engineer existing source code: http://www.uml-lab.com/en/uml-lab/tutorials/reverse-engineering-tutorial/. Basically, just create a new Model and Class Diagram and all available PHP source files are imported automatically. Otherwise you can import a PHP file by dragging it onto the diagram editor.

The tool supports Java and PHP, and has build-in support for Zend Framework. It may not understand each PHP source file - but files containing a class should work fine. If there is something the tool doesn't understand you'll be notified and can directly file a bug.

It's a commercial tool, but there is a 30 days trial and a free academic edition. If you have any questions don't hesitate asking them in the forum, bug tracker or by mail.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I was looking for free/open source product.